# Android disable multi send request from Fragmemt

Tags: android

I'm using `NodeJs` on server to send and request response, my service and send request and get response work fine when i send request from activity, but when i try to send request from `Fragment` request is duplicate and twice at moment and i cant fix this problem

My Service:

```
public class SignalChatServiceProvider extends Service {
    private SignalApplication signalApplication;
    private Realm             realm;
    private String            marketUUid;

    public static SignalChatServiceProvider instance = null;

    public static boolean isInstanceCreated() {
        return instance == null ? false : true;
    }

    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalChatServiceProvider getService() {
            return SignalChatServiceProvider.this;
        }
    }

    public void IsBendable() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (isInstanceCreated()) {
            return;
        }
        super.onCreate();
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Utils.toast("onCreate",getBaseContext());

            }
        });
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        signalApplication = (SignalApplication) getApplication();

        if (signalApplication.getSocket() == null)
            signalApplication.CHAT_SOCKET = signalApplication.getSocket();

        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);

        //@formatter:off
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getMarketBanners"                , getMarketBanners);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getMarketProducts"               , getMarketProducts);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getProductImages"                , getProductImages);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getMarketRandomProductImages"    , getMarketRandomProductImages);
            signalApplication.getSocket().on("getRandomMarketLists"            , getRandomMarketLists);
        //@formatter:on

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (isInstanceCreated()) {
            return 0;
        }
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        connectConnection();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getMarketBanners = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getMarketRandomProductImages = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
    };


    private Emitter.Listener getProductImages = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getRandomMarketLists = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
    };

    private Emitter.Listener getMarketProducts = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
    };

    private void connectConnection() {
        instance = this;
        signalApplication.getSocket().connect();
    }

    private void disconnectConnection() {
        instance = null;
        signalApplication.getSocket().disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (!realm.isClosed())
            realm.close();

        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        signalApplication.getSocket().off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);

        //@formatter:off
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getMarketBanners"                , getMarketBanners);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getMarketProducts"               , getMarketProducts);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getProductImages"                , getProductImages);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getMarketRandomProductImages"    , getMarketRandomProductImages);
            signalApplication.getSocket().off("getRandomMarketLists"            , getRandomMarketLists);
        //@formatter:on

        disconnectConnection();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(EventChangeChatServerStateEvent event) {
        switch (event.getState()) {
            case connected:
                instance = this;
                connectConnection();
                break;
            case disconnected:
                instance = null;
                disconnectConnection();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

My Activity to disable multi running service:

```
if (SignalApplication.signalApplication.getSocket() != null && !SignalChatServiceProvider.isInstanceCreated()) {
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignalChatServiceProvider.class));
    doBindService();
}
```

now when i try to send request with this code from activity:

```
SignalApplication.signalApplication.getSocket().emit("getRandomMarketLists");
```

request count is one

My Fragment is into `ViewPager` :

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FragmentMainMarkets.newInstance();
        ...
    }
}
```

when i try to send request from `FragmentMainMarkets` Fragment, request is twice a moment